# JavaScript convert array of objects in array 2D

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, request-promise

I need the following JS structure (results from request-promise query)

```
[ { idfactura: 2,
    idcuenta: 1,
    nombre: 'Nick',
    periodo: 'Per1                                          ',
    formapago: 'Tarj   ',
    cantidadpersonas: 1,
    subtotal: 7000,
    porcentajedescuento: 0,
    fecha: '24/11/2017 02:38' },
  { idfactura: 3,
    idcuenta: 1,
    nombre: 'Adm',
    periodo: 'Per1                                          ',
    formapago: 'Efec  ',
    cantidadpersonas: 1,
    subtotal: 7000,
    porcentajedescuento: 10,
    fecha: '25/11/2017 23:45' } ]
```

To the exact following structure (to export in xlsx):

```
[[2, 1, 'Nick', 'Per1', 'Tarj', 1, 7000, 0, '24/11/2017 02:38'],
 [3, 1, 'Adm', 'Per1', 'Efec', 1, 7000, 10, '25/11/2017 23:45']]
```

*I've tried with `_` method, values, JSON.stringify as other posts in Stackoverflow but I am not able to get my exact output struct.*

Example Code:

```
results = [ { idfactura: 2,
    idcuenta: 1,
    nombre: 'Nick',
    periodo: 'Per1                                          ',
    formapago: 'Tarj   ',
    cantidadpersonas: 1,
    subtotal: 7000,
    porcentajedescuento: 0,
    fecha: '24/11/2017 02:38' },
  { idfactura: 3,
    idcuenta: 1,
    nombre: 'Adm',
    periodo: 'Per1                                          ',
    formapago: 'Efec  ',
    cantidadpersonas: 1,
    subtotal: 7000,
    porcentajedescuento: 10,
    fecha: '25/11/2017 23:45' } ]

var arr = Object.key(results).map(function(key){
    return [results[key]];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the values from each object. While there are many ways, one way is where you can get the keys using `Object.keys` and map the values respectively using `map` function.

In `ES7` you can just get the values of object using `Object.values`

Also since your array seem to have un-necessary spaces, you need to map them accordingly by trimming the spaces.

```js
results = [ { idfactura: 2,
    idcuenta: 1,
    nombre: 'Nick',
    periodo: 'Per1                                          ',
    formapago: 'Tarj   ',
    cantidadpersonas: 1,
    subtotal: 7000,
    porcentajedescuento: 0,
    fecha: '24/11/2017 02:38' },
  { idfactura: 3,
    idcuenta: 1,
    nombre: 'Adm',
    periodo: 'Per1                                          ',
    formapago: 'Efec  ',
    cantidadpersonas: 1,
    subtotal: 7000,
    porcentajedescuento: 10,
    fecha: '25/11/2017 23:45' } ]
    
const mappedResults = 
  results.map(result => 
    Object.keys(result).map(key => 
      typeof(result[key]) === "string" ? result[key].trim() : result[key]
    )
  )
console.log(mappedResults)

const mappedResultsES7 = 
  results.map(result =>
     Object.values(result).map(value =>
       typeof(value) === "string" ? value.trim() : value
     )
  )
 
console.log(mappedResultsES7)
```

Comment: your snippet does not executes in my nodejs linux terminal (nodejs --version
v4.8.2 )  .:    ```const mappedResults =
...   results.map(result =>
...     Object.keys(result).map(key =>
.....       typeof(result[key]) === "string" ? result[key].trim() : result[key]
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list```

Comment: Which node are you using? You are missing something while copying because this works on the browser and on the code snippet.

Comment: (version 4.8.2)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of keys in the order that you want, then use 2 nested [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls to iterate the array, and then to iterate the keys and extract the data:

```js
var oredredKeys = ['idfactura', 'idcuenta', 'nombre', 'periodo', 'formapago', 'cantidadpersonas', 'subtotal', 'porcentajedescuento', 'fecha'];

var data = [{"idfactura":2,"idcuenta":1,"nombre":"Nick","periodo":"Per1","formapago":"Tarj   ","cantidadpersonas":1,"subtotal":7000,"porcentajedescuento":0,"fecha":"24/11/2017 02:38"},{"idfactura":3,"idcuenta":1,"nombre":"Adm","periodo":"Per1","formapago":"Efec  ","cantidadpersonas":1,"subtotal":7000,"porcentajedescuento":10,"fecha":"25/11/2017 23:45"}];

var result = data.map(function(o) {
  return oredredKeys.map(function(key) {
    return o[key];
  });
});

console.log(result);
```